# How to set different x and y axis for each subplot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a table with products and categories.
I want to create subplots for each category.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'Category':["Toys","Toys","Toys","Toys","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Furniture","Furniture","Furniture"], 
        'Product':["AA","BB","CC","DD","SSS","DDD","FFF","RRR","EEE","WWW","LLLLL","PPPPPP","LPO","NHY","MKO"],
       'QTY':[100,200,300,50,20,800,300,450,150,320,400,1000,150,900,1150]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = px.bar(df, x="Product", y="QTY", barmode="group",facet_col="Category")
fig.show()
```

[image]

But I get the same x and y axes in the charts. How can I set for each plot a coordinate axis for its data?
That is, the x-axis will have only products that belong to the same category. The y-axis maximum value will be equal to the maximum quantity in each category..

Comment: I guess it would be better to make three bar plots and then adjust them in a subplot. [Here](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) you can see how subplots work.

Comment: Hi, mosc9575. This data is just an example, the real data include around 100 categories. So is not a better way to make separately each bar plot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to make all axes for each subplot fit their corresponding x and y values and ranges:

```
fig.for_each_xaxis(lambda t: t.update(fixedrange=True))
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda t: t.update(fixedrange=True))
```

#### Plot 1

[image]

But as you can see, `yaxis2` and `yaxis3` won't have ticklabels in place out of the box. So I would include `facet_col_spacing = 0.075` in `px.bar()` and  `showticklabels=True)` in `fig.for_each_yaxis()`.

#### Plot 2

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'Category':["Toys","Toys","Toys","Toys","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Food","Furniture","Furniture","Furniture"], 
        'Product':["AA","BB","CC","DD","SSS","DDD","FFF","RRR","EEE","WWW","LLLLL","PPPPPP","LPO","NHY","MKO"],
       'QTY':[100,200,300,50,20,800,300,450,150,320,400,1000,150,900,1150]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
fig = px.bar(df, x="Product", y="QTY", barmode="group",facet_col="Category",
             facet_col_spacing = 0.075)

fig.for_each_xaxis(lambda x: x.update(fixedrange=True))
fig.for_each_yaxis(lambda y: y.update(fixedrange=True, showticklabels=True))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hi, @vestland. I think you're mistaken in the code because it returns the same plots to me as in the beginning. (with the same x-axis for all plots)

Comment: @Galat I just double-checked. The code snippet above does return the provided screenshot. What is your plotly version?

Comment: 5.3.1 in Jupyter notebook

Comment: @Galat Strange. Could you just make sure that the code is exactly the same as mine, and run it after you've restarted the kernel?

Comment: see here  @vestland https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SWTgYVsGGQiuinABMJGGH0a85vs7_S2O/view?usp=sharing all after the restart

Comment: @Galat Very, *very* strange. It's working perfectly on my end. I'm also on `5.3.1`. Could you verify your version in the same image by running `import plotly; plotly.__version__`?

Comment: import plotly; plotly.__version__     5.3.1 version you use Jupyter ?

Comment: @Galat JupyterLab